# Who are Faltines (Dormammu like beings) really, is there any mention of their dimension in MCU comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In Doctor Strange, we are told about Dormammu, a creature residing in the Dark Dimension, feeding upon matter. Apparently he's part of a species known as the [*Faltines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormammu).

The [Marvel Wiki article on Dormammu](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Faltine) mentions that he and another (Umar) were born out of Sinifer, who used to feed on energy only. But the new Faltines fed on matter and ended up eating Sinifer which made all other Faltines furious and both Dormammu and Umar were exiled to the Dark Dimension.

So where was Umar when Dormammu came to Earth? And is there any mention of the Dimension of the Faltines in the MCU movies or more importantly MCU comics?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, [Umar](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Umar_(Earth-616)) (and the Faltines generally)  don't exist in the MCU. Dormammu is just a big entity thing with zero back-story.

Comment: Fanpages suggest [more](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Faltine)

Comment: [Clea might be present in *Dr. Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*](https://screenrant.com/doctor-strange-2-cast-sorcerer-clea-rumors/), so we might have a proper answer after that movie comes out.

Comment: @Renan - Although her backstory will likely just be relegated to 'sorceress that Strange meets'.

Comment: @Renan a single dormammu was hard to defeat without the time loop, what about an whole army of them!

Comment: @StellaRigeo not all of them are evil though, Clea is his lover and Clea's little brother is Strange's student.

Comment: @BabaYaga Fanpages appear to be talking about [the comics the MCU was inspired by](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Faltine/Mentions), not the MCU itself.